# performance of find in an unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I wanted to make sure and I couldn't readily find this information.

What is the performance characteristic of find() in an unordered map? Is it as fast/nearly as fast as a normal lookup?

I.e.

```
std::string defaultrow = sprite.attribute("defaultrow").value();
auto rclassIt = Rows::NameRowMap.find(defaultrow);
if (rclassIt != Rows::NameRowMap.end())
    defRow = rclassIt->second;
```

vs.

```
std::string defaultrow = sprite.attribute("defaultrow").value();
defRow = Rows::NameRowMap[defaultrow];
```

where `Rows::NameRowMap` is a unordered map mapping a string index to an int.

In my case, I don't know for certain if the key will exist before hand, so the first solution seemed safer to me, but if I can guarantee existence, is the second case faster (ignoring the extra checks I'm doing)? and if so, why? If it matters, I'm using the 1.46 boost implementation

Comment: Those two code samples do different things.

Comment: Could you explain how? The end result is to assign the integer mapped by defaultrow to defRow. I realize they're not equivalent if the string doesn't hash to a value, but if it does aren't they equivalent?

Comment: If there is no `defaultrow` in the map, then the first one will not add one. The second one will **create** an entry if it doesn't already exist. Therefore, you're returning data that is default initialized.

Comment: @Megaton: Like Nicol says, the second modifies `Rows::NameRowMap`. So later, if you just do an existential check, it'll exist even though it *really* doesn't...it's only empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` and `operator[]` on an unordered container are O(1) average, O(n) worst-case -- it depends on the quality of your hash function.

Comment: Just beware of the memory hit for an unordered list.  You are trading size for speed...

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty possible that `operator[]` uses `find` and `insert` internally. For example, IIRC that's the case with Miscrosoft's `std::map` implementation.

EDIT:
What I was trying to say is that `operator[]` is not magical, it still has to do a lookup first. From what I see in Boost 1.46.0 both `find` and said operator use `find_iterator` internally.

Usually it's better to use `find` for lookups, because your code will be more reusable and robust (e.g. you will never insert something accidentally), especially in some kind of generic code.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same amortized complexity of O(1), but the operator also creates a new element when the value is not found. If the value is found, performance difference should be minor. My boost is a little old - version 1.41, but hopefully it does not matter. Here is the code:

```
// find
//
// strong exception safety, no side effects
template <class H, class P, class A, class G, class K>
BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME hash_table<H, P, A, G, K>::iterator_base
hash_table<H, P, A, G, K>::find(key_type const& k) const
{
    if(!this->size_) return this->end();

    bucket_ptr bucket = this->get_bucket(this->bucket_index(k));
    node_ptr it = find_iterator(bucket, k);

    if (BOOST_UNORDERED_BORLAND_BOOL(it))
        return iterator_base(bucket, it);
    else
        return this->end();
}

// if hash function throws, basic exception safety
// strong otherwise
template <class H, class P, class A, class K>
    BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME hash_unique_table<H, P, A, K>::value_type&
hash_unique_table<H, P, A, K>::operator[](key_type const& k)
{
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME value_type::second_type mapped_type;

    std::size_t hash_value = this->hash_function()(k);
    bucket_ptr bucket = this->bucket_ptr_from_hash(hash_value);

    if(!this->buckets_) {
        node_constructor a(*this);
        a.construct_pair(k, (mapped_type*) 0);
        return *this->emplace_empty_impl_with_node(a, 1);
    }

    node_ptr pos = this->find_iterator(bucket, k);

    if (BOOST_UNORDERED_BORLAND_BOOL(pos)) {
        return node::get_value(pos);
    }
    else {
        // Side effects only in this block.

        // Create the node before rehashing in case it throws an
        // exception (need strong safety in such a case).
        node_constructor a(*this);
        a.construct_pair(k, (mapped_type*) 0);

        // reserve has basic exception safety if the hash function
        // throws, strong otherwise.
        if(this->reserve_for_insert(this->size_ + 1))
            bucket = this->bucket_ptr_from_hash(hash_value);

        // Nothing after this point can throw.

        return node::get_value(add_node(a, bucket));
    }
}
```